# How to add timedelta for each time seperately contain in one column using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with on input and date and time. Here I just want to convert time into 00:00:00 for specific value which is contain in input column, and other time will be display as it is. Then I wrote the code for that. Then what I want is specify that 00:00:00 only. So I wrote the code for it.

Here is my code:

```
data['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

data['duration'] =  np.where(data['X3'].eq(5), np.timedelta64(0), pd.to_timedelta(data['time']))

print (data['duration'].dtype)
def f(x):
 ts = x.total_seconds()
 hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
 minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
 return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

 data['duration'] = data['duration'].apply(f)

 match_time="00:00:00"
 T = data.loc[data['duration'] == match_time, 'duration']
```

Then I got the output :

[image]

Then what I want to do is I just want to add 6hours for each time series Then I wrote the code for it and it gave me just 0  values without separate.

my code:

```
def time (y):
S=[]
row=0
for row in range(len(T)):
    y = "00:00:00"
    while row >0:
        S = np.array(y + np.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(6))
        row += 1
        break
    else:
        continue
#break
return
A= T.apply(time)
print(A)
```

then output came:

[image]

But what I expected is :

```html
T            add timedelta 1hr till to 6 hrs        expected output
00:00:00                                             01:00:00
                             "                       02:00:00
                                                     03:00:00
                                                     04:00:00
                             "                       05:00:00
                                                     06:00:00

00:00:00                     "                       01:00:00
                                                     02:00:00
                                                     03:00:00
                                                     04:00:00
                                                     05:00:00
                                                     06:00:00
                                                     
 00:00:00:00                                         01:00:00
                                                     02:00:00
                                                     03:00:00
                                                     04:00:00
                                                     05:00:00
                                                     06:00:00
```

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

Comment: Very confused about what you want and what you wrote. I guess there is indentation mismatch with data['duration'] = data['duration'].apply(f). However, this line of code doesn't change anything. Please, present a final output example you want,

Comment: @kantal I hope now you can understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's what you thought:

```
My test data frame:
T= pd.DataFrame({"T":[ "00:00:00" for i in range(3) ]},index=np.random.randint(0,100,3))

           T
8   00:00:00
96  00:00:00
44  00:00:00

tims=[ dt.time(i).strftime("%H:%M:%S") for i in range(1,7)] 

['01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00', '06:00:00']


dd=T.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({"T":"00:00:00", "Hours":tims}), axis=1)

           T                                              Hours
8   00:00:00  [01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00...
96  00:00:00  [01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00...
44  00:00:00  [01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00...

dd.explode("Hours")

           T     Hours
8   00:00:00  01:00:00
8   00:00:00  02:00:00
8   00:00:00  03:00:00
8   00:00:00  04:00:00
8   00:00:00  05:00:00
8   00:00:00  06:00:00
44  00:00:00  01:00:00
44  00:00:00  02:00:00
44  00:00:00  03:00:00
44  00:00:00  04:00:00
44  00:00:00  05:00:00
44  00:00:00  06:00:00
96  00:00:00  01:00:00
96  00:00:00  02:00:00
96  00:00:00  03:00:00
96  00:00:00  04:00:00
96  00:00:00  05:00:00
96  00:00:00  06:00:00
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking forward. I have a one question , Can I write this code inside the class, and If I want to continue this code then how to write it?

Comment: @team What's your class?

Comment: If I wrote def convert_time(T): inside of this class can I write these codes that you provide ?

Comment: @team "def convert_time(T):" will be a function, not a class. If  function, yes. It must return dd.explode("Hours").